# Finding Selected object index in an Array @iphone Sdk

Tags: arrays, ios4, nsarray

Im going to implement one application that includes sorting functionality.

Here i have two arrays, one array name is "listOfItems" and another one is that "copyListOfItems".

Here after successfully sorting the array its adding to "copyListOfItems", from this array i'm taking the selected string value and finding that same "STRING" value in the main array called "listOfItems".

Here i have used below logic:-

NSLog(@"My Index  %d",[listOfItems indexOfObject:selectedCountry]);

but m not able to get that index, can anyone please help in this.

Answer (score 0):

<s>Right below indexOfObject: in the reference doc was indexOfObjectIdenticalTo:</s>

Actually, I was wrong.  indexOfObject should do it.  You've obviously got another problem.  Are you sure your strings are identical?  Are you sure you're actually passing the right string to indexOfObject?  Are you sure your array even exists?

Comment: by using this "indexOfObjectIdenticalTo" the same output m getting, any other way please

Comment: Yes, Daaniel i'm passing the string only. My code is NSLog(@"My Index  %@",selectedCountry);

Comment: Most likely either: 1) your strings have not been "trimmed" of leading/trailing blanks, or 2) one of your arrays is actually a nil pointer (which happens very frequently when people don't understand what they're doing with Objective-C).

Answer (score 0):

IndexOfObject always works fine with me especially with NSStrings. Otherwise, you can loop your entire array and use [NSString isEqualToString:NSString].

Try to display the objects inside the loop before comparing and see if that object (in this case an NSString) is really there.

Also, try trimming the selectedCountry. There might be a space or unwanted character there.